# Gradle process dont stop after test execution

Tags: gradle, automated-tests

I am using Gradle, TestNG and Restassured for my testing project. I have a build.gradle file which triggers a testng xml file to run tests.

```
test{
    useTestNG() {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        suites 'src/test/suite.xml'
    }
}
```

When I run my test on IntelliJ IDE, i can track execution progress. But when I run "gradle test" command, test execution progress is always "0 Tests completed". In case I wait as long as my whole suites execution time, I can see that all tests are finished.(I create an HTML report at the end of my suite.) But command line is on hold with "0 tests completed".

```
   Automated API Tests STANDARD_OUT
        Integration3rdPartyTests
    <=========----> 75% EXECUTING [2m 9s]
    > :test > 0 tests completed
    > :test > Executing test api.integrations...ClinicTests
```

I tried "gradle test --debug-jvm" and attached to the proccess, all tests are running fine. But it seems gradle dont understand that test started, in progress or done state.

Tests were running fine a few weeks later. I never run those test from commandline since 3 weeks, I only added some new dependency and a few new tests. That's the only change.

Did anyone had the same problem.

I am using Gradle 4.8.1 , TestNG 6.14.3 and RestAssured 3.0.2 and working on MAC OSX